# Reinitializing a pod class allocated with new

Tags: c++

Long irrelevant story of how I got here... Personally I find it neat and it seems to work just fine, are there any technical problems with this?

```
struct banana {
    int size;

    banana(int size) {
        this->size = size;      
    }
};

int main() {
    auto b = new banana(5);
    *b = banana(6);    // <- reusing the constructor
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: You're not "reusing" the constructor here, you're just using the default assignment operator along with a temporarily constructed object. Also, manual memory management will always be more dangerous than using smart pointers.

Comment: `are there any technical problems with this?` You are using dynamic allocation unnecessarily. And unsafely. And the constructor is seemingly unnecessary as well; the class might as well be an aggregate.

Comment: That whole program is pointless, not just the allocation, so what? Its a minimal example. Also if I were in a situation where the performance hit of a smart pointer was acceptable, I'd be making the example with a smart pointer. There is no point fearmongering about the pitfalls of manual memory management, its one of the languages greatest strengths and one of the primary reasons to use the language in the first place. Thank you for pointing out that it is in fact the default assignment operator that I'm calling there, thats useful.

Comment: @user81993 `so what?` You asked if there were problems. I told you what the problems are. That's what. `if I were in a situation where the performance hit of a smart pointer was acceptable` Why do you imagine that there would be a  performance hit?

Comment: @eerorika **Technical** problems, anything related to the actual question would have been fine too. As for smart pointers - they aren't smart for free.

Comment: @user81993 It is unclear what you think qualifies as a **technical** problem and what doesn't. Some smart pointers are free as long as you use an optimiser.

Comment: @eerorika Natural language skills should be enough to guide you there. For instance, what you addressed were *design* problems. Smart pointers definitely aren't free in my specific case and usually aren't in situations where even the consideration of the cost of smart pointers comes up.

Comment: @parktomatomi Try rebalancing a tree while using smart pointers and tell me there is no cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to ask: is this OK and doesn't break any C++ rules? Then sure, it's valid.

Just as valid as:

```
banana b(5);
b = banana(6);
```

or:

```
banana b(5);
banana& br = b;
br = banana(6);
```

I wouldn't call it reinitialization. It's just assignment - setting the value(s) of one instance from another.